# How to achieve insertion order from multi threads Kafka producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have an Ingres DB with History table, which logs DB events like insert update and deletes.
I have a producer which will be multi-threaded.
This producer will read the History table to find which table and which row to pick and then that row will be added Kafka topic.
Now the producer needs to make sure the events are added to the Kafka topic in the same way the History table has logged In.
So the consumer reads them in the same order it is logged in History table and executes it on Postgrace DB.

I can able to produce that data into multiple producers.
Example

```
Producer1 has message 1 to 5
producer2 has message 6 to 10
producer3 has message 11 to 15
```

But when I consume I am getting messages on a topic like

```
messageId 1
messageId 2
messageId 3
messageId 6
messageId 7
messageId 11
```

and so on

I want to get all messages in below order

```
messageId 1
messageId 2
messageId 3
messageId 4
messageId 5
messageId 6
messageId 7
messageId 8
messageId 9
```

and so on

NOTE : - I have 1 topic and 1 partition and 1 consumer

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't guarantee order when sending down data, since there's by default several partitions per topic, and if you don't have a key, messages are assigned randomly to partitions.  And downstream, each partition can be consumed from independently.

If you need to guarantee insertion and consumption order, you'd need to configure your Kafka topic to only use 1 partition.  That is the only way to guarantee order in Kafka. However, you'd be losing a lot of of the benefits of kafka, which are high performance distributed across multiple servers, cores, etc.

Answer (score 0):

At most you can keep the order of messages in the order they are created by producer by sending to a single partition. Kafka partitions guaranteed the order of consuming the messages, in the order it was created within partition.

In your scenario, messages are generated by multiple producers and they are not in sync to populate the partition with messages in order. So it is impossible to achieve the order in consumer end as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Google's recommendation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering), if you use a synchronous publisher (producer) and a single subscriber, follow the algorithm in the Node JS code in [the 2nd half of the page](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering) to guarantee ordering of processing.

Similarly, if you have multiple publishers, you need to synchronize the publishers by having a critical section between getPublishCounterValue method and setPublishCounterValue method, which defeats the multi-threaded nature of the publisher.

The best solution is to follow [the section of](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering)

> Order in the final result matters
>
> Typical Use Cases: Logs, state updates

the multi-threaded publishers must attach a timestamp to every pub/sub event message so the subscribers can store the event messages in [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) or [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) as entities. A separate event message processor cron job can retrieve the entities of event messages in a timestamp sorted manner to enforce message ordering.